# Implementing styles from Support Library v7 in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-support-library

I`m trying to implement Support Library v7 in my project and having issues with an style which are bundled with it.

```
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: 

No resource found that matches the given name

 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar.'.
```

I`ve already included *com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1* in my build.gradle, but it does not help.

here is my build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

and here is my styles.xml which causing an error

```
<resources>
   <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"> </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar."></style>
 <!-- erorr here -->
</resources>
```

I`m using Android Studio 1.4 with buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your style. **Remove the dot.**

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

instead of

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar.
```

Comment: thank you. looks like it works. Damn you Android Studio auto-completion system !